# Need to get samaccountname and name/cn laravel ldap-record

Tags: laravel, collections, attributes, ldap

My code so far:

```
public function getClerks() {

    $group = Group::find('CN=Clerks Internet,OU=Clerks,OU=Department,DC=mydomain,DC=com');

    $members = $group->members()->get();    //->flatten()->all();
    dd($members);
}
```

Need to get samaccountname and name/cn from the laravel collection that this gives.

The Collection:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer.

```
public function getClerks() {

    $group = Group::find('CN=Clerks Internet,OU=Clerks,OU=Department,DC=domain,DC=com');

    $members = $group->members()->get();    
    $keySearch = "samaccountname";
    $membersList = $members->toJson();
    $jsonObj = json_decode($membersList);
    $accounts = array_column($jsonObj,$keySearch);
    foreach($accounts as $account){
        echo $account[0]."<br>";
    }
}
```